# Python: Unbound method __init__() from import.class

Tags: python, import, subclass

I'm trying to subclass a class from another python script.

I've done the following when subclassing from within the same file, and it works.

```
widge.py
    class widget(object):
        def __init__(self,bob):
            #do something

    class evenWidgetier(widget):
        def __init__(self, bob):
            widget.__init__(self,bob)
            #do something
```

But once I add in inheritance from another file..

```
superWidget.py

    import widge
    class superWidgety(widge.evenWidgetier):
        def __init__(self, bob):
            widge.widget.__init__(self,bob)
            #do something
```

I get an error:

```
unbound method __init__() must be called with widget instance as first argument
```

Is there a way I can subclass a class from another package that works?

.

And out of curiosity, what's the deal?
Substantively this looks identical to me. I can call a class from another file by using the widge.widget(), so that method seems established. And I can subclass when the class is in the same file by referencing the class in the declaration. What is it about using a class from an import in a declaration that breaks? Why does it see itself as the right method when in the same file, but sees itself as an unbound method when imported?

The specifically, my code is this (stripping the parts that shouldn't affect this.

```
Attributor.py
    class Tracker(object):
        def __init__(self, nodeName=None, dag=None):
            #Tracking stuff

    class Transform(Tracker):
        #Does stuff with inherited class

timeline_tab.py
    import Attributor as attr

    class timeline(attr.Transform):
        #some vars
        def __init__(self, nodeName=None):
            attr.Transform.__init__(self,nodeName=nodeName)
            #Additional init stuff, but doesn't happen because error on previous line
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you initialize the class...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error message you gave for the minimal example you wrote.

Comment: Are you sure the subclass is actually a subclass in your actual code? The error message is suggesting that `self` is not an instance of the parent class, which it should be if the inheritance is working properly.

Comment: *Substantively this looks identical to me* -- It is identical. You have not posted the code necessary to reproduce the issue. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: One thing to be careful of... if you were doing development and ever reloaded `widge`, you have to reload the second module too. Even that doesn't always seem reliable. e.g. `import widge; w1; import subclass; reload(widge); w2` somehow seems to get where at w1, `widget` is actually `w1.widget`, then the import class is a subclass of `w1.widget`, then you reload and now it's `w2.widget` and the subclass is no longer seen as a subclass. You may just have to restart the python session in this case.

Comment: The code this comes from is much larger, so I was trying to create a shorter example. I think what I missed is that I'm creating a subclass of a subclass in another python file. I'll edit the script to include.

Comment: @ColinKnueppel - Does the example you've posted here cause the issue you're describing?

Comment: That end code is pretty much issue. The script worked previously when they were all in the same class, but once I split off the timeliner into a separate class that used it, to declutter the source class from special cases, it broke.

Comment: I'm glad you have resolved your problem, but I'd like to point out that still the new code you have posted is perfectly find :) Try to post code that reproduces the issue the next time you ask a question: this will increase the chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `superWidget.py` change the `SuperWidget` to use `super`

```
    import widge
    class superWidgety(widge.evenWidgetier):
        def __init__(self, bob):
            super(SuperWidget,self).__init__(bob)
            #do something
```